# Counting types of files with global variables

Tags: bash, counting, subdirectory

I have a recursive function (mandatory that it's recursive) that travels through directories and looks at type of files (dir, file, sock, pipe, char, block, or link), but I don't know what approach to take. I was thinking something with global variables:

```
count(){
   for path in "$1"/*;do

        if [ -d "$path" ];then
            ndir=$((ndir+1))
            count "$path" 
                        continue
        fi
        if [ -L "$path" ];then
            nlink=$((nlink+1))
            continue            
        fi
            if [ -c "$path" ];then
            nchar=$((nchar+1))
            continue
        fi  

            ....

}

ndir=0
nfile=0
nsock=0
npipe=0
nchar=0
nblock=0
nlink=0

count $filename

printf "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d" $ndir $nfile $nsock $nblock $nlink $nchar $npipe
```

Would something like this work?

Comment: Before asking if "something like this works", have you actually tried it?

Comment: doesn't work, something is amiss

Comment: maybe remove the periods, and add the `done` keyword to close the `for ... do` statement?

Comment: and then complete with all the other types...

Comment: And to impress your instructor, replace `ndir=$((ndir+1))` by `((++ndir))`.

Comment: And to impress him even more, replace the single square brackets by double ones: replace `if [ -d "$path" ]; then` by `if [[ -d $path ]]; then` and tell him that's the more modern and robust way to do in bash.

Comment: It works, thanks man, impressed instructor :D